# How can I model one class having a instance-specific count of instances of another class?

Tags: java, class, oop, modeling

If I have two different classes (say, person class and commodity class), how do I represent each person's individual demand (a number) for each good?

If I initialize say 10 instances of the person class, and then 5 different types of good: each person has their own personal demand for each type of good, but if I only initialize the good class as a separate class (so we'll have 5 instances of the good class in this example), how do I give each instance of the person their own specific demand for each of the 5 good instances?

I don't really know how to ask this in clearer language and hope I was specific enough that you know what I'm trying to ask. Please reply if you have questions!

EDIT:
So to clarify:

Each commodity has a price, worked out by its supply (exogenous, independent, set variable) and its demand (endogenous, worked out from the population).

Each pop has a different randomized amount of wealth at the start of the model, a double from 0.0 to 100.0. Each pop also has a demand for each commodity, personalized to them.

If I initialized 5 goods: apples, bananas, cheese, bread, butter, each pop would then have 5 different demands for each good, and (blah blah econ stuff calculations) to work out how much of their wealth they're willing to spend on each good.

So it's that pop-specific private demand variable I'm wanting to know about:

How can I construct my pops in a way where they'll have n number of private float variables denoting demand for different goods, that corresponds to n number of goods I initialize?

Comment: Can you give each person a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), mapping from good to demand?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit ? So if I understand you have two classes : Person and Commodity. What attributes do these classes have ?

Comment: I edited the title to (hopefully) clarify what you're asking. If it doesn't match your intentions, you can re-edit it.

Comment: So to clarify:

Each commodity has a price, worked out by its supply (exogenous, independent, set variable) and its demand (endogenous, worked out from the population). 

Each pop has a different randomized amount of wealth at the start of the model, a double from 0.0 to 100.0. Each pop also has a demand for each commodity, personalized to them. If I initialized 5 goods: apples, bananas, cheese, bread, butter, *each* pop would then have 5 different demands for each good, and (blah blah econ stuff calculations) to work out how much of their wealth they're willing to spend on each good.

Comment: So how can I construct my pops in a way where they'll have n number of private float variables denoting demand for different goods, that corresponds to n number of goods I initalize?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of simple ways to implement this; which one is more appropriate might depend on how you need to use a `Person`'s commodity demands.

The first idea is for each `Person` to hold a `Map` of `Commodity` to count, to indicate which commodities, and how much of of each, that person demands. Something like this:

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;

@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Commodity {

    @Getter
    private UUID id;

    @Getter
    private String name;
}
```

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Person {

    private Map<Commodity, Integer> demands = new HashMap<>();

    public void setDemand(Commodity commodity, Integer count) {
        demands.put(commodity, count);
    }

    public Optional<Integer> getDemand(Commodity commodity) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(demands.get(commodity));
    }
}
```

The other option, which might make more sense if you need to, for example, track a `Demand` as a distinct class in your model, would be for `Person` to have a set of `Demand`s, with each `Demand` referencing a `Commodity` *and* a count. So, given the same `Commodity` class above, something like this:

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Demand {

    private Commodity commodity;
    private int count;
}
```

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Person {

    private List<Demand> demands = new LinkedList<>();

    public void addDemand(Commodity commodity, Integer count) {
        addDemand(new Demand(commodity, count));
    }

    public void addDemand(Demand demand) {
        demands.add(demand);
    }
}
```